# Facebook OAuthSwift redirect_uri not supported iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am trying to use `OAuthSwift` to get the user's `access token` in my app. I already did this with `Twitter` and `Instagram`, but `Facebook` is not helping me.

The code I am using is the following:

```
    func doOAuthFacebook () {
    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    "@@@@",
        consumerSecret: "####",
        authorizeUrl:   "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth",
        responseType:   "token"
    )
    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(NSURL(string: "myApp://myApp/facebook")!, scope: "publish_stream,email", state: "FACEBOOK", success: { (credential, response, parameters) -> Void in

        self.showAlertView("Facebook", message: "oauth_token:\(credential.oauth_token)")

        }) { (error) -> Void in

            print (error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The `callbackURL` that I am using works for the other two social networks. From Facebook I am receiving this message when Safari tries to open the page:

`The redirect_uri URL is not supported`

I don't know if I have to do something to my app in `Facebook Developers` page, or it is something else.

Comment: Why not use the Facebook SDK?

Comment: I am using OAuthSwift Framework to do the same for Instagram and Twitter, I am trying to mantain the Facebook request similar

Comment: The redirect_uri must be https and the same value as the value that was registered when you did the client registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is documented in project wiki page 
https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/wiki/API-with-only-HTTP-scheme-into-callback-URL

two way:

- have an http server and redirect to your application scheme
- use a delegate into a webview to handle fake http url and redirect to your application scheme or call directly 
      OAuthSwift.handleOpenURL